# android App closes with no error when imageview is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple imageview with an id and trying to start an activity when it is clicked but when i click it in the emulator, the app just crashes and gives me (wait or close the app prompt)
here is my:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:src="@drawable/twoth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my java code

```
public class MainUi extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables Declaration.
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    private ImageView img;


    //Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ui);
        //Variables Initialization and OnClick Method


        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Start another activity
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainUi.this, Query.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: is Query defined in your manifest? Does your logcat display any errors?

Comment: what is the resolution of your image @drawable/twoth ? If its too large and you did not resize it to correct drawable folders, it can be memory issue.

Comment: The 'wait or close' thing leads me to think there's something in Query activity that is doing a lot of work on the main thread. Could you post any code that might take a long time to process and is in the Query activity?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianComan, it was in the query activity, i deleted all the code in this class just to get to know what is the problem and its in the Query class, it was because there is no connection to the server SOCKET, can you help me handle that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'wait or close' thing leads me to think there's something in Query activity that is doing a lot of work on the main thread.

Try to use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put all your long running processes in the doInBackground part and later handle the response in the onPostExecute.

I guess it depends a lot of what you are actually doing, but AsyncTask should be a good start.

Comment: I did, and it is actually the problem here, the serversocket was closed, and i tried to connect to it ( in the asyncTask  doInBackground), leading to 'wait or close'. i want to handle that in a way such that if the socket connection failed it will show a toast, can you please guide me on how do i do that ?

Comment: Can you give some extra info regarding how you connect to the socket? Or what you are doing in the onPostExecute/onPreExecute?

Comment: i will make it in an answer to this post better.

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code, I added the rest of the code just in case you can handle it from the outer (Query) class and not within Async Class.

```
public class Query extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String[]> BB;
    private ArrayList<String[]> AA = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_query);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        try {
            AA = new AsyncAction().execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            setTextViews();


        }
    }

    public void setTextViews() {
        View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.info);
        for (int y = 0; y < AA.size(); y++) {
            // for (int x = 0; x < AA.get(0).length; x++) {}
            TextView name = new TextView(this);
            name.setText(AA.get(y)[0]);
            name.setId(y);
            name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            name.setTextSize(30);
            name.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 0);
            name.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.icons));
            name.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));

            ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
            Drawable drawable = pb.getProgressDrawable();
            drawable.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
            pb.setProgress(100);

            final int finalY = y;
            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putStringArray("list", AA.get(finalY));
                    Intent i = new Intent(Query.this, Info.class);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(name);
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(pb);

        }
    }


    private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {

        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {


                socket = new Socket(port, 8888);
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
//                action
                out.writeInt(2);
                try {

                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    BB = (ArrayList<String[]>) in.readObject();


                    in.close();
                    socket.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            return BB;//returns what you want to pass to the onPostExecute()
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
            AA = result;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the get from AA = new AsyncAction().execute().get(); let it just like AA = new AsyncAction().execute();

Comment: Error:(47, 47) error: incompatible types: AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String[]>, and am getting an arraylist from the server.

Comment: Modify your class to suit the data you are receiving: AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> or ArrayList<String[]>. Same thing with the onPostExecute()

As well in the onPostExecute, try and use an interface to communicate with your activity the result.

Comment: it works well, but how would that let me know if connecting to serversocket was successful or not so i can handle it?

Comment: Not very familiar with how sockets work, but I think it will throw a SocketTimeoutException that you can catch and handle.